# Why do people call Worf Son of Mogh after he joins House Martok?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

After he is invited into House of Martok, he is still addressed as Son of Mogh, why?

Comment: welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question as it stands is incomplete, and will attract votes to close. Please edit your question, giving as much information as necessary to enable replies that do not require guesswork or assumptions. Explain why you are asking this question. Do you think he should not be addressed that way?

Answer (score 9):

### Because he is.

That is, the appellation "son of Mogh" literally means that his father was named Mogh. The fact that he's also of the House of Mogh is coincidental. (Mogh might have (re)named the house after himself, or he might've been named after the ancestor who did, as Worf was named after Mogh's own father Worf.)

Alexander, for instance, would be "Alexander, son of Worf, of the House of Mogh".

Comment: Interestingly every Great House appears to have the same name as its senior member at the point when a Star Trek series that it first appears in starts, and none is ever seen to be renamed (except perhaps the House of Quark).

Comment: I would expect it's fairly common to name one's children after the founder of a house, so maybe it's not "Larry, son of Larry, son of Larry", but alternating between a small number of oft-used names.